# Is it possible to move a subview of one view to another view by dragging?

Tags: iphone, view, drag, subview

I have a view which I want to move by dragging.
This view is in a view 1.
I'd like to move the view to view 2.
Where view 3 has view1 and view2 as subviews.

Is this possible or should I merge view1/view2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you start to detect the move, you could remove the view from view1 and add it to view3.  When the move stops, you can remove it from view3 and add it to view2.

Comment: umm, i'd thought about it, but if user starts the move but don't move much, i'd like that view to go back to view1. then i'll have to look at where the view resides (either view1 or view3) when touch ends.  Is this the best solution? :(

Comment: i just tried removing and adding to superview. the view blinks at superview. i guess it's frame info is messed up;

Comment: Yes, determine where the view is when the move ends and respond accordingly.